# multiple conditions else / if statement somehow wrong?

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean, conditional-statements

I'm doing a hackernet challenge where n is an int input. The conditions are:

- If n is odd, print Weird
- If n is even and in the inclusive range of 2 to 5, print Not Weird
- If n is even and in the inclusive range of 6 to 20, print Weird
- If n is even and greater than 20, print Not Weird.

Im sure the code makes logic and dont think theres syntax. It gives the correct responses and hackernet still says its incorrect so ive come here to see if anyone can see what the problem is

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int N = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

    if (N % 2 != 0 || N % 2 == 0 && N >= 6 && N <= 20)
    {
        System.out.print("weird");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("not weird");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please learn correct indentation. It makes your code easier to read. I've fixed it for you this time. Where is `scanner` declared and initialized? Does hackernet hide that stuff or something?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the logic in your `else` condition, which would also catch values of `N` which are less than 2.  Try this version:

```
if (N % 2 != 0)
{
    System.out.print("weird");
}
else if (N >= 2 && N <= 5 || N > 20)
{
    System.out.print("not weird");
}
else if (N >= 6 && N <= 20)
{
    System.out.print("weird");
}
else
{
    // NOTE: if the code still fails, remove this else condition
    System.out.print("unexpected value of N");
}
```

Note: To get your code to pass the Hackernet task, you might have to completely remove the `else` condition.  I added it for completeness, but Hackernet might test `N=1` to see if nothing gets printed.

Comment: Nice answer. I didn't want to do his work, but always nice to have a competent person giving a good solution.

Comment: I'm in a meeting right now actually, but I'd rather be on Stack Overflow :-P

Answer (score 1):

Read this condition :

```
if (N % 2 != 0 || N % 2 == 0 && N >= 6 && N <= 20)
```

as

```
if (N % 2 != 0 || (N % 2 == 0 && N >= 6 && N <= 20))
```

Then see how operator precedence changes the behaviour and yield desired results.

Comment: Not "grouping". Operator precedence! Still, have my vote, as I was just to lazy to put down all the required brackets here ...

Comment: Agreed, I wanted to explain in very naive terms. :)

Comment: Newbies are enough naive by themselves. Part of growing up is to learn the words that matter ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
 private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int n = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
            if (n % 2 == 1 || (n >= 6 && n <= 20)) {
                System.out.println("Weird");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not Weird");
            }
            scanner.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following one

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int N = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

        if(N%2!=0) {
            System.out.print("weird");  
        }else if(N>=2 && N<=5) {
            System.out.print("not weird");
        }else if(N>=6 && N<=20) {
            System.out.print("weird");
        }else if(N>20) {
            System.out.print("not weird");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the technical part: start by reading about 
[precedence of java operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) and then make your code easier to read.

Pushing that many conditions into a single if is **not** helpful. You see it yourself: you think the code is correct, but probably it isn't. And now you look to other people to explain your overly complex code back to you. And of course, all the other answers do all that for you ... but beyond that:

The "real" answer here is: learn how to **test** your code.

Instead of having a main that somehow asks for a number, and then makes decisions, write a method `boolean isWeird()` that takes a number and returns true/false according to your requirements.

And then simply *test* that method with all reasonable cases. And then check if that result is as expected.

Using JUnit, you could write something like

```
 assertThat(isWeird(1), true);
 assertThat(isWeird(21), true);
 assertThat(isWeird(22), true);
 ...
```

Ideally, you write such tests **before** you implement that method. And then you implement all the conditions, and any check that fails tells you that you got something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I feel, In the if (N % 2 != 0 || N % 2 == 0 && N >= 6 && N <= 20) condition, you are verifiying the odd and even values at same time using && and || operator. Can you modify the condition into like this if (N % 2 != 0 || (N % 2 == 0 && N >= 6 && N <= 20)) and check? If N is odd weird will be printed or if N is even and it falls under the 6 and 20 inclusive, weird will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a good few answers here but if you think logically about what you actually need, you can break it down easier.

It looks like the only `"Not Weird"` print out is `2`, `4` and even numbers `> 20`

So an example could be something like:

```
if (n % 2 == 0) {
    if ((n >= 2 && n <= 5) || (n > 20)) {
        return "Not Weird";
    }
}
return "Weird";
```